# Propensity Score Matching and subset the data by using a weighting factor in R

Tags: r

I'm doing Propensity Score Matching and want to subset the data for treatment and control by using weights. There are 5 variables: ID, treatment(yes/No), Outcome(Yes/No), Age and "Weights". I was trying to write a programme in R, but have problems to do this according to weights. The `survey` package is used.

`dput(dat2)`:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
    Weight = c(2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 1.9548149, 1.9548149),
    Age = c("35-44", "<15-24", "25-34", "35-44", ">45", "25-34"),
    Treatment = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    Outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

`head(dat2)`:

[image: head(dat2)]

```
data<-svydesign(ids = ~dat2$Id,
                weights = ~dat2$Weight,
                data = dat2)
treat<-subset(dat, dat2$treatment==1)
cont<-subset(dat, dat2$treatment==0)
```

I am sharing sample of data. I have 1587 rows. When I am finding dimensions  without weights then the dimensions of treat and cont is 877*5 and 710*5 respectively. But with weights it will be 803*5 and 784*5.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please copy-paste your data as text, not as image

Comment: or maybe you can `dput()` your data?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as below:

**Sample Data**

```
dat2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
               Weight = c(2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 1.9548149, 1.9548149),
               Age = c("35-44", "<15-24", "25-34", "35-44", ">45", "25-34"),
               Treatment = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
               Outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Script**

```
data<-svydesign(ids = ~dat2$ID,
                weights = ~dat2$Weight,
                data = dat2)

treat<-subset(data, Treatment==1)
cont<-subset(data, Treatment==0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Majid . But this is giving same results as without weights

Comment: Please add your desired output in the bottom line of your post.